# How do I return date with milliseconds

Tags: datetime, vertica, milliseconds

I'm struggling to return a date with milliseconds...

I've tried

```
my_date::datetime
```

and

```
my_date::timestamp
```

but both only return to the second?

Surely there's a way of doing this? Documentation isn't too helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `my_date` column also has to contain the millisecond component (I'm assuming that it's of a `timestamp` type). Have you verified that it does?

```
dbadmin=> CREATE TABLE date_test (my_date timestamp);
CREATE TABLE
dbadmin=> INSERT INTO date_test (my_date) VALUES (SYSDATE());
 OUTPUT
--------
      1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> INSERT INTO date_test (my_date) VALUES ('2015-01-30 09:43:41');
 OUTPUT
--------
      1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> COMMIT;
COMMIT
dbadmin=> SELECT my_date::timestamp FROM date_test;
          my_date
----------------------------
 2015-01-30 09:46:48.746415
 2015-01-30 09:43:41
(2 rows)
```